# Using csv value in "if" statement

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

The last line of my csv file is `10/18/19,11:52,22.8,999.4,40.1`
so `((x[2]))` will be `22.8`

Why can't I use this value in the `if` statement? I assume it's how I am defining the `if` statement to recognize the value of `22.8`, but not sure what to google to find an answer and yes, I am very very new to python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import csv

import subprocess
last_line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-1", "humidity1.csv"])

x = last_line.split(",")
print ((x[2]))
((x[2])) = y
if y > 100:
    print("AAA")
else
    print("BBB")
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import csv



import subprocess
last_line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-1", "humidity1.csv"])


x = last_line.split(",")

print float(x[2])  



y = float(x[2])

if y > 1:
    print("AAA")
else:
    print("BBB")
```

Comment: The result of splitting a string is *smaller strings*.  Your `x[2]` isn't `22.8`, it's `"22.8"`, which isn't something that is meaningfully comparable to `100`.  You are apparently using Python 2.x, which returned an arbitrary result in such cases; 3.x produces an error.  Try using `float(x[2])`, which gives you a numeric value that can actually be compared to other numbers.

Comment: You have the assignment backwards. It's `destination = source`.

Comment: You're missing a quote in `print(BBB")`

Comment: And your `else:` is missing the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the order where you define y.

`y = ((x[2]))`

The way you're showing it would likely throw a NameError when you try to run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```